# How to embed a webpage using php or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a webpage and I want to embed an external webpage on another server but I don't want any frame bars, and was hoping to use Php or Javascript to do this. The website I'm building is build using php.

I've tried

```
<?php
$remote = fopen("http://www.myotherwepage.com/apage", "r");
fpassthru($remote);
?>
```

But won't load properly no images will load and the style won't load.

This is the page I'm trying to embed

http://brands.datahc.com/?languageCode=EN

and I have my own (includes)naviagtion above and (includes)footer underneath.And it will need to expand and reseize for the user.

Comment: Why not just style an `iframe` as you require?

Comment: If you are going to try and dump the HTML from another page into your page, you are going to need to fix all the relative paths to various resources in that page. And even if you fix all those, you may well run into cross-domain problems. Just use an `iframe` already. You can style it to not show scroll bars.

Comment: @BenM do iframes resize automatically though? _And it will need to expand and reseize for the user._

Comment: Yes, they can be programmed to resize automatically, even on another domain... http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

Comment: By the way: Are you aware of potential copyright problems which might be caused by this? Just injecting someone elses content into your own website might be a copyright violation.

Comment: @BenM: The problem with your solution (which I've used myself before) is that you need to control BOTH sites. It requires JS to run on both the parent and the iFramed site.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `iframe` element, and then style it using CSS. You can manipulate its size using jQuery or vanilla JS.

This way, you don't need to worry about fixing any broken or relative links. For example, the following code will turn off the scrollbars for the `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="http://brands.datahc.com/?languageCode=EN" srcolling="no"></iframe>
```

You could in turn look to implement some of the following functionality > http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/. This will also ensure that the iframe is resized according to its content.

Comment: Iframe doesn't seem to work and re sizes to default size with bars, and I want to move away from the iframe as it's not HTML5 compliant.

Comment: @JohnnyQ: What makes you think it's not HTML5 compliant? HTML 5 even adds the new `seamless` and `sandbox` properties to `iFrame`. See [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/html5-iframe-attributes.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all the images on the website are embedded with relative paths.

When you embed the website example.**com** which refers to an image http://example.com/image.jpg, its sourcecode only reads `src="image.jpg"`. When you then integrate the sourcecode of that website into example.**org**, the image will be searched on http://example.org/image.jpg where it doesn't exist.

As a solution you could

- rewrite all relative links and image paths by using a HTML parser or
- use [the HTML `<base>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base) in the `<head>` of your website and set it to the url of the page you are embedding. That way the users web browser will interprete all relative URLs as relative to the embedded page, not the url of your own page.